# How do I calculate percentage amino acid composition of sequences contained in a large FASTA file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I want to calculate the amino acid composition of every sequence separately contained in a FASTA file but I'm having difficulty doing this. I know I can do it using the code below but that involves me inputting every sequence in separately rather than taking the FASTA file as a whole and calculating it that way.

```
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis 
X = ProteinAnalysis("MAEGEITTFTALTEKFNLPPGNYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLRILPDGTVDGT" 
                "RDRSDQHIQLQLSAESVGEVYIKSTETGQYLAMDTSGLLYGSQTPSEEC" 
                "LFLERLEENHYNTYTSKKHAEKNWFVGLKKNGSCKRGPRTHYGQKAILF" 
                "LPLPV") 
print(X.count_amino_acids()['A']) 
print(X.count_amino_acids()['E']) 
print("%0.2f" % X.get_amino_acids_percent()['K']) 
print("%0.2f" % X.get_amino_acids_percent()['L']) 
print("%0.2f" % X.molecular_weight()) 
print("%0.2f" % X.aromaticity()) 
print("%0.2f" % X.instability_index()) 
print("%0.2f" % X.isoelectric_point()) 
sec_struc = X.secondary_structure_fraction() 
print("%0.2f" % sec_struc[0]) 
epsilon_prot = X.molar_extinction_coefficient()  
print(epsilon_prot[0])   
print(epsilon_prot[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read the FASTA file of sequences using `SeqIO.parse()`:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis

for record in SeqIO.parse('myfasta.fa', 'fasta'):
    X = ProteinAnalysis(str(record.seq))
    print('\n### Results for record: {} ###'.format(record.id))
    print(X.count_amino_acids()['A']) 
    print(X.count_amino_acids()['E']) 
    print("%0.2f" % X.get_amino_acids_percent()['K']) 
    print("%0.2f" % X.get_amino_acids_percent()['L']) 
    print("%0.2f" % X.molecular_weight()) 
    print("%0.2f" % X.aromaticity()) 
    print("%0.2f" % X.instability_index()) 
    print("%0.2f" % X.isoelectric_point()) 
    sec_struc = X.secondary_structure_fraction() 
    print("%0.2f" % sec_struc[0]) 
    epsilon_prot = X.molar_extinction_coefficient()  
    print(epsilon_prot[0])   
    print(epsilon_prot[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something from the [`FastaIO`](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO-module.html) module, e.g.:

```
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis 
from Bio.SeqIO import FastaIO

with open('myfile.fasta') as fd:
  for name, sequence in FastaIO.SimpleFastaParser(fd):
     X = ProteinAnalysis(sequence)
     print(name, X.count_amino_acids()['A'])
```

and whatever you want to calculate

Comment: As it says in the link you put "You are expected to use this module via the Bio.SeqIO functions.".  However, this does have the advantage of being faster than using SeqIO.parse, although less flexible